# Exit batch file after spawning new process

Tags: windows, batch-file, notepad

I'm writing a batch script to convert Unix line endings to DOS:

```
@ECHO OFF
TYPE %1 | MORE /P >%1.1
MOVE %1.1 %1 > NUL 2>&1
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
EXIT
```

I want the Command Prompt window to close after opening Notepad. However, `EXIT` doesn't appear to be doing this. What can I do, without using VBScript or anything other than Batch?

Comment: I hope your files are not larger than 65,535 lines.

Comment: @Squashman What difference, exactly, would that make? And thanks for the edit, I forgot that *tags should be used for what the question is about, not what it contains*.

Comment: Well you could always test it and find out.

Comment: @Squashman Sure, let me just pull up my handy 65,535-line text file that will open in Notepad without crashing...

Comment: `more.com` writes 65534 lines from the input, and then writes "-- More  --"  and waits.

Comment: Notepad will not crash opening a 65,000 line file depending on the overall file size in bytes and how much memory you have on your computer.  I do it all the time.  I do data processing for a living so you can't BS me on this subject.  An easy test would have been to just use a `FOR /L` command to write a single byte 66,000 times to a file.  Then use your code above to see what it does.

Comment: @Squashman You do data processing for a living and you use Microsoft Notepad to do it? Lol :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file waits until command is finished before processing the next comand

You need to launch the process asynchronously using `start`

```
start "notepad" C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1
```